# CSS Center responsively

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, center

I have a centered webpage and for now I have resized it using media-queries but I don't know how I can achieve something like on stackoverflow itself. Once you decrease the width of the page, it's gettings smaller and smaller and the margin-left is decreasing towards zero; so at one point the page fills the whole window. I use a lot of `margin-left: 25%` to have the page centered, but this does not work like the design I want. Once I resize the browser window, the pages width gets smaller and it stays centered, while I don't really want the width to get smaller, but rather decreasing the space at the left and right of the page.

This is for example a title I use:

```
margin-top: 3%;
float:left;
font-size: 350%;
margin-left: 25%;
width:10%;
```

This is the "middle" of the site which has a white background:

```
position: absolute;
border-radius: 3px;
top: 0px;
left: 21%;
width: 58%;
min-height: 100%;
background: white;
z-index: -1;
-webkit-box-shadow: 20px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), -20px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
-moz-box-shadow: 20px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), -20px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
box-shadow: 20px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), -20px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
```

Sorry, this is probably quite easy, but I somehow really don't get it...

Thanks

Comment: The absolute positioning context might be the problem. What does your relevant HTML look like? It’s not entirely obvious to me what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Usually to center a block element that has a width, you'd give a margin-left:auto/margin-right:auto or.. margin:0 auto;

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle including your HTML please?

Comment: You can see it perfectly on http://onlinehelp.avs4you.com/de/AVS-Video-Editor/Features/SavingVideos/index.aspx . The site always has the same width when you resize it, but the margin left and right get smaller and at some point there is no margin anymore. I think the way I center the elements (margin-left: 20%) is somehow wrong or something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to set your left and right margins to auto. Not 25%.

Like this:

`margin-left:auto;`

`margin-right:auto;`

But you have to define a width of your container to which the `auto` values are applied.

If you take a look at the CSS of the example site you provided in your comment:

```
#mainbody {
   width: 980px; /*this line*/
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: top;
   padding: 0;
   margin: auto; /*this line*/
   height: auto;
   background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks I didn't really understand `margin: auto;`. Now it's working fine with a wrapper div and two auto margins. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Here is a nice reference for margin and explanation of the values -- [margin CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin)